# Developer Team Instant Messaging Tool

Tags: instant-messaging

we would like to use an IM tool for regular developer communications. Security is a concern. So we would like to install an open source server to an internal server. Must-have features we need:

1. open source server
2. windows/linux/mobile clients
3. share files
4. multiple clients logged at the same time with sync'ed conversations across clients
5. searchable global history (preferably stored on server)

Alternatives we have evaluated so far:

- Jabber can do 1-3, but clients we have tested failed 4 and 5.
- HipChat (and its upcoming server edition) are good clients, they are
  not open source, so we can not guarantee messages are kept in
  company.

Answer (score 0):

Email. (CC, BCC ftw!)

For files this thing called "version control".

Thunderbird for the desktop client, Android's stock will do fine not sure about other OSs, and a decent IMAP server will let the basic email client search.

Protip:

Version control isn't for sharing and syncing files (rsync FTW!) but for versioning, if you have a programmer and he doesn't know what version control is please please go to the local market and buy a really big fish, take it by the tail and slap him as hard as you can across the face with it.

Comment: I should have mentioned, sorry. Our C++ programmers have shown great success sending and receiving email. We managed to run our SVN server too. I wasn't aware that email could do *instant* messaging and one could send others files over version control systems. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul IMAP is not for polling these days :) Instant notification when the mail comes through, the bytes for storage are trivial. You can also attach things.